# Using back and forward buttons with url variables and window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a variable on this page called `artist` and it is put in the url after one of the buttons in the main artist page is clicked, such that the url changes to `?artist=foo`. If the page is linked using the new URL, the site will automatically load the correct artist page. However, after one of the buttons is clicked and I go to press the back button on my browser, the site doesn't consider the url variable and the content remains the same. Here is some example code where pushState is used:

```
var returnartists = function(){
$('#artist-container').css("z-index","-1");
$('#artist-container').animate({
    opacity: "0",
    left: "-1000px"
}, 1500);
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 50
}, 500);
$('#artistButtons').animate({
    opacity: "1",
    left: "0px"
}, 1500);
$('#artistButtons').css("z-index","1");
try
{
    window.history.pushState("title", "Title", "artists.html");
}
catch(err)
{

}
}
```

Here is some js where the url variable is interpreted:

```
var filterInArtist = function(){
var artistParam = getParameterByName("artist");
if (artistNames.indexOf(artistParam) !==-1)
{
    filterArtist(artistParam);
}
}
```

Here is a link to the site: http://www.hokosounds.com/final-redesign/artists.html

I was wondering if this can be accomplished using jQuery

Comment: Can you show your JavaScript code here?

Comment: You have to listen to the `popstate` or `statechange` event to detect when the back button is pressed and, when that happens, you should make the page, using JavaScript, return to the initial state. (So right now you can go to the main page to the artist page via JavaScript, you then have to implement the other "direction".)